# Why use `^` to get specific sbit in C51?

Tags: keil, c51

```
sbit OV = PSW^2
```

`^` here is just XOR([ref](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a166/a166_op_xor_c.htm)) operator right? Not overloading or something.

How could I get `sbit` with the XOR operator?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ask a question about `C51` and then reference a document from the `A51` manual, they are different things (although they do share similarities as well).

In your statement, the `^` is **NOT** the `xor` operator:

In the definitiopn of `sbit` in the [C51 manual](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm), they explain that the character `^` is used to denote the bit position in the byte address of the SFR.

This syntax is only valid for **Declaration** code lines.

If used inside the program, then the `^` operator is the standard bitwise `xor` operator from the standard `C` language (not specific to `C51`).